# Cannot display image icon

Tags: java, swing

I have to display images using the fly weight pattern, I can't get the images to print to screen, here's the code that demonstrates the problem.

```
    public void draw(Graphics g, int tx, int ty, String name) {
       grem.paintIcon(null, g, tx, ty);
        g.drawString(name, tx, ty + H + 15 );
         ImageIcon grem = new ImageIcon("../images/grem.png");
    }

/// next class that calls the above class

 public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Folder folderIcon;
        String name;

        int j = 0;      //count number in row
        int row = Top;  //start in upper left
        int x = Left;

        //go through all the names and folders
        for (int i = 0; i< names.size(); i++) {
            name = (String)names.elementAt(i);
            if (name.equals(selectedName))
                folderIcon = fact.getFolder(true);
            else
                folderIcon = fact.getFolder(false);
            //have that folder draw itself at this spot
            folderIcon.paint(g);

            x = x + HSpace;    //change to next posn
            j++;
            if (j >= HCount) { //reset for next row
                j = 0;
                row += VSpace;
                x = Left;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome!What lib do you use? (and add this lib to the tags of your message)

Comment: What is the purpose of line 3 inside `draw()`? It loads a new copy of the same image, entirely violating the flyweight principle, and then it's not used for anything.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the code in no way demonstrates the use of a flyweight pattern.  Perhaps you should say "here's the code that in no way demonstrates the problem"

Comment: yea that me just trying different things trying to get to work

Comment: lets forget its the flyweight pattern for one minute what am i doing wrong to use the draw method to display the image?

Comment: Neither your sample code nor the problem you're describing (image doesn't display on the screen) have anything to do with the flyweight pattern. Start by getting *an* image to display, then use a flyweight pattern to do so efficiently. These are separate tasks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't override paint(). Custom painting is done by overriding paintComponent().
2. Don't do I/O in a painting method. You can't control when Swing will repaint a component so you don't want to read images in the painting method. The images should be read in the constructor of your class.
3. Override the `getPreferredSize(...)` method to return the size of your component, otherwise the size of the component will be (0, 0) so there may be nothing to paint (depending on the layout manager being used.
4. If you need more help the post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem because we don't know the context of how your code is being used and don't have time to spend guessing what you may or may not be doing.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information. Also, instead of doing custom painting you could also use a JList to display the Icon in a grid pattern. Check out the table of contents for the tutorial link to find the section on `How to Use Lists` for more information.

Comment: thats aload of crap and you dont know if he's using JPanel or whatever

Comment: @gpasch, Which is why I asked for a `SSCCE` in case my crystal ball was wrong. I stated the obvious problems given the information provided. Yes it is an assumption that the paint() method is an overridden method of a JPanel. Why do you think this is NOT a logical assumption? How else to you do custom painting if you don't override a painting method?

Comment: plus one and missing there some reason for grem.paintIcon inside draw (paint, paintComponent)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the null is the problem : it should be something like this if im not mistaken

```
  class MyComponent extends JComponent {
  public void paint(Graphics g) {

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("a.png");
    int x = 0;
    int y = 100;
    icon.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
  }
```

Comment: that makes sense but for some reason still no joy with it, thanks for the input

Comment: yea no problem this is a separate class that was supposed to display the image

Answer (score 0):

public class Gremlin extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

```
String names[] = {"Andy","Bill","Bob","Dan","Eugene","Frank","Gary","Harry","Ian","Jack",
        "Killlian","Liam","Mark","Nial","Obi","Phil","Richard","Stephan","Terry","Viny",};   // 20 names

public Icon img = new ImageIcon("grem1.jpg");
public JLabel grem = new JLabel(img);
JLabel bigLabel = new JLabel();
JLabel grem2 = new JLabel("New Gremlin");

public JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

public Gremlin() {



    JButton button = new JButton("Add Gremlin");

    this.add(panel);



    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(9,6));

    panel.add(panel2);
    panel2.add(button);
    for(int i = 0; i<20; i++){
        bigLabel.add(grem = new JLabel(names[i]), panel.add(grem = new JLabel(img)));
        panel.add(bigLabel);    

    }
    button.addActionListener(this);

    setSize(550,600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gremlin frame = new Gremlin();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(e.getSource() != null ){
        System.out.println("add a Gremlin");

        panel.add(grem = new JLabel("NEW GREMLIN"), panel.add(grem = new JLabel(img))); 
        revalidate();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: this is the solution i came up with for my question.